# How to type a square bracket in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

So, I'm learning to make Android apps and got stuck for about four hours now trying to type opening square bracket ([) in Android studio and just can't figure it out.

Usually to type it I'll hold down control+alt+f but that has some action (it highlights a part of the code and a popup shows up) that is not on the Keymap in the Settings.